# What is the meaning of Wired Memory in OS X?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is in wired memory?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31801/what-is-in-wired-memory)

Recently I bought a MacBook Pro Core i5 with 4GB Memory (RAM).

After using Xcode and quitting it, all of my memory is committed and I have only 100 MB of free RAM.

So I closed all of my remaining apps, but RAM usage is still high and I don't had much free memory.

What's happening? And what is the meaning of Wired in system memory?