# When memory usage is too high for too long, macOS becomes unresponsive while finder, dock and menu bar continually open and crash

Tags: finder, google-chrome, memory, crash, dock

```
Catalina 10.15.6 (19G73)
MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)
2.4 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9
32 GB RAM
```

While Chrome chews through memory, it seems to somehow do this through `kernel_task`. Eventually (after a few days), macOS will freak out and whatever is responsible for the system/OS UI (dock & menu bar) crashes. Dock and menu bar disappear. Open apps are still visible but unresponsive. Fans spin up to full blast. After 10-15 seconds, dock and menu will reappear, then eventually crash/disappear again. This continues (crash, open, crash, open) and doesn't seem to recover. I eventually have to hold the power button to restart the computer.

I recently migrated to this computer from a 2015 Macbook Pro. That computer behaved exactly the same in terms of Chrome memory but it simply just got slow over time, as Chrome ate up RAM and things moved to swap. It never freaked out this way. That computer was running Mojave and had 16GB RAM.

Comment: What do you qualify as 'too high for too long'? What does memory pressure look like when this happens?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to open Activity Monitor when this happens.

Comment: Then leave it open & set it to All Desktops.

Comment: As far as "too high", I periodically check Activity Monitor to see how it's going. The pressure is actually never that high (was very high on the 2015 MBP) but memory usage does get close to 32GB. Again, this is when I'm looking at Activity Monitor before the crashing starts.

Comment: We don't have enough to go on. kernel_task itself shouldn't be using much RAM (mine shows about 50 - 100**KB** after 17 days uptime, no sleep). Chrome is a known memory-hog, but without specifics, we're just guessing. Unless memory pressure starts to show red, there is no issue.  see https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvB06.png

Comment: Thanks - I'll circle back here if I can capture some more info

Comment: `kernel_task` is currently showing 18.83 GB of Real Mem: https://imgur.com/a/wBEonMR memory pressure is not high: https://imgur.com/a/vQsWELy

Comment: That's some serious wired memory usage (though right at that moment you're not in any actual trouble, yet). idk how you'd fix or even test that. Have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31801/what-is-wired-memory & see if it might hint at where else to look.

Comment: About 30 minutes after I commented here, macOS freaked out again.