# Change output format of "top" command in Mac OS for memory usage?

Tags: command-line, bash, memory

I am using the top command in Mac OS from [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/46655/335256) answer to grab memory usage:

```
$ top -l 1 -s 0 | grep PhysMem

PhysMem: 5490M used (2569M wired), 11G unused.
```

Can I go from that to possibly printing out "Used / Total"?

Like so:

```
PhysMem: 5.49G / 16.0G
```

or just:

```
5.49G / 16.0G
```

**Side questions:**

Would that final top command be suitable to run in a few second interval and the output used for something later? Or is this not the best or most efficient command for grabbing this info and I should use something else?

I am basically trying to replicate what Luke Smith did in his [video](https://youtu.be/MNwpdqD_I8Y), but in Mac OS for fun, and so I can try to learn this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going off of @TheMadsen's answer above, you can setup a bash script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    top -l 1 -s 0 | grep PhysMem | awk 'BEGIN {S["G"]=1024; S["M"]=1} 
     /PhysMem:/ {U=substr($2, 1, length($2)-1) * S[substr($2, length($2))];
                 N=substr($6, 1, length($6)-1) * S[substr($6, length($6))];
                 printf("%.2fG / %.2fG\n", U/1024, (N+U) / 1024)}'
sleep 1
done
```

If you run this script it will periodically run the command in the background (changing the new line parameter in the `printf` statement from `\n` to `\r` updates it on the same line).

Otherwise you can set up a `cron` job to run the command periodically

---

Comment: This was exactly what I needed and works great for me. Do happen to know the impact of running a script like this on a 1 second or so interval? Probably a negligible hit to the cpu / memory and what not right? Or no?

Answer (score 2):

A bit verbose, but the following awk snippet does this

```
$ echo 'PhysMem: 5490M used (2569M wired), 11G unused.' \
  | awk 'BEGIN {S["G"]=1024; S["M"]=1} 
         /PhysMem:/ {U=substr($2, 1, length($2)-1) * S[substr($2, length($2))];
                     N=substr($6, 1, length($6)-1) * S[substr($6, length($6))];
                     printf("%.2fG / %.2fG\n", U/1024, (N+U) / 1024)}'
```

5.36G / 16.36G